# Conditional statement if attribute set id is

Tags: attribute-set

I know there are many ways to do things in Magento, could someone explain to be the best approach to show an asset within a product page if the attribute set ID matches?

I have used this before for a product attribute, but do not understand how to fetch and match an attribute set ID?

```
<?php if ($_product->getAttributeText ('bogof') == "Yes"): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('')->toHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the attribute set ID with below code.

```
$_product->getAttributeSetId()
```

On a side note, retrieving a static block like that is not really best practice. Try using the layout XML

```
<catalog_product_view>
   [...]
   <reference name="product.info">
      <block type="cms/block" name="bogof_block">
         <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>bogof_block</block_id></action>
      </block>
   </reference>
   [...]
</catalog_product_view>
```

and in the `view.phtml` for the product

```
if ($_product->getAttributeSetId() == 4) {
   $this->getChildHtml('bogof_block');
}
```